# Selenium @FindBy find by one xpath or another

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to find an element on a page using

```
@FindBy(xpath = "somexpath")
WebElement someElement;
```

The problem is sometimes the element's xpath is slightly different (because of a failed login message that is displayed in the same table). How can I find an element by one xpath or another? Something like

```
xpath == "somexpath1" || xpath == "somepath2"
```

I've tried doing a repeating annotation, like this:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "somexpath1")
@FindBy(xpath = "somexpath2")
WebElement someElement
```

but that won't compile. And I've tried using @FindBys but that seems to work like &&  rather than ||.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So I did a little digging and I found @FindAll, which does exactly what I need. You do it like this. 
    `@FindAll({@FindBy(xpath = "xpath1"), @FindBy(xpath = "xpath2")}) WebElement webElement;`
This returns the first element it finds matching any of those FindBys.
Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several paths can be combined with `|` separator, which effectively works as a logical OR.

```
@FindBy(xpath = "somexpath1 | somexpath2")
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer a bit?

Answer (score 1):

Try using like this :

```
@FindAll({ @FindBy(id = "id1"), @FindBy(id = "id2") })
```

If both id's are available you will get a list containing both elements else only one element either `id1` or `id2`.

It works fine for me.